# Erlang / Removing warnings when some behavior callback functions are not implemented

Tags: erlang

What is the best practice from removing warnings when I don't need to implement all the callback functions of a behavior ?

For instance:

```
Warning: undefined callback function code_change/3 (behaviour 'gen_event')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "best" practice is actually to implement stub callbacks, with sensible return values (such as `{reply, ok, State}` for calls, `{noreply, State}` for casts and info etc.). This will also ensure stability and compatibility if someone would ever try a code upgrade, for example, on your code.

There is no way to ignore these warnings currently.

Comment: It's also recommended to log the calling of the stub function as an error: `error_logger:error_msg("Unexpected function call in ~p~n", [mymodule])`. This way you get informed as the method is accidentality called.